# Can't include a global variable in domain of a plot in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Consider the following piece of code to be include in a `\begin{axis} ... \end{axis}` of `pgfplots` package:

```
    \newcommand{\lineasVolumen}[3]{%

      % #1,2 Volumen inicial, volumen final, #3 paso.

      % Líneas de volumen constante:
      \FPeval{\segundo}{(#1) + (#3)}

      \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \volumen in {#1,\segundo,...,#2}{%

      \addplot[white,samples=201,name path global=lineaVolumen,
                                 domain=\minTs:\maxTs]
        {621.98*(((\Pt)*(\volumen))/(287 *(x+273.159)) - 1)};
      \path [name intersections={of=lineaSaturacion and lineaVolumen,
                           by=E}];

      % Para dibujar las coordenadas x,y de la intersección:
      \node[anchor=south, fill=white, fill opacity=0.75,text opacity=1] at (E) {
       \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
       \transformxdimension{\macrox}
       \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},%
       \transformydimension{\macroy}%
       \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult} 
    };

    \node at (E) { 
      \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
      \transformxdimension{\macrox}
      \global\edef\coordX{\pgfmathresult}
    };

    \node at (E) {\coordX}; % HERE WORKS FINE.

    \addplot[purple,samples=201,domain=\coordX:\maxTs] % HERE IT'S WRONG.
        {621.98*(((\Pt)*(\volumen))/(287 *(x+273.159)) - 1)};    
   }

 }
```

When I run pdflatex I obtain the following error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \pgfplots@plot@domain ->\coordX 
>                                  :\maxTs
>
> > l.259   \lineasVolumen{0.75}{0.95}{0.05}

I'm very frustrated because I tried to find a solution by Internet being unsuccessful.

We need to hold the x coordinate of a intersection and, then, to use in domain of `\addplot`.

Please, I need help!
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Here the code:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[a4paper,landscape,
                left=1.5cm,right=1cm,
                top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,
        headsep=0cm,footskip=0cm]
               {geometry}

    \usepackage{pxfonts} % palatino con símbolos matemáticos (incompatible amsmath)           

    \usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
    \renewcommand\shorthandsspanish{} % evita conflictos con tikz (ver spanish.pdf y
                              % notas.txt)
    \spanishdecimal{,} %\decimalpoint

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    %\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \usepackage{fp}
    \usepackage{xifthen}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand\transformxdimension[1]{
        \pgfmathparse{((#1/\pgfplots@x@veclength)+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x}
    }
    \newcommand\transformydimension[1]{
        \pgfmathparse{((#1/\pgfplots@y@veclength)+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@y)/10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y}
    }
    \makeatother

    % PARÁMETROS DEL DIAGRAMA ******************************************************

    \newcommand{\ancho}{192mm}
    \newcommand{\alto}{122mm}

    \newcommand{\Pt}{101325} % en pascales (101325 a nivel del mar)

    \newcommand{\minTs}{-10} \newcommand{\maxTs}{55}
    \newcommand{\pasoTsPral}{5} \newcommand{\pasoTsSec}{1}  % para rejilla de Ts

    \newcommand{\minW}{0} \newcommand{\maxW}{33}

    \newcommand{\Pvs}{exp((16.461*x-114.86)/(x+231.67))}

    \newcommand{\lineasVolumen}[3]{%
      % #1,2 Volumen inicial, volumen final, #3 paso.
      % Líneas de volumen constante:
      \FPeval{\segundo}{(#1) + (#3)}

      \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \volumen in {#1,\segundo,...,#2}{%

        \addplot[white,samples=201,name path global=lineaVolumen,domain=\minTs:\maxTs]
                {621.98*(((\Pt)*(\volumen))/(287 *(x+273.159)) - 1)};
        \path [name intersections={of=lineaSaturacion and lineaVolumen,by=E}];

        % Para dibujar las coordenadas x,y de la intersección:
        \node[anchor=south, fill=white, fill opacity=0.75,text opacity=1] at (E) {
          \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
          \transformxdimension{\macrox}
          \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},%
          \transformydimension{\macroy}%
          \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult} 
        };

        \node at (E) { % sólo aquí funciona, pero \x sólo vale en otro entrecorchete
          \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
          \transformxdimension{\macrox}
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{\pgfmathresult}
          \global\edef\coordX{\xx}
        };

        \node at (E) {\coordX};

        \addplot[purple,samples=201,domain=\coordX:\maxTs]
                {621.98*(((\Pt)*(\volumen))/(287 *(x+273.159)) - 1)};    
      }

    }

    % ******************************************************************************

    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}

    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[width=1.3*\ancho,height=1.3*\alto,
                   domain=\minTs:\maxTs,domain y=\minW:\maxW,
                   xmax=\maxTs,ymin=\minW,ymax=\maxW,
                   title={},
                   axis x line=bottom,xtick={\minTs,-\pasoTsPral,...,\maxTs},
                   axis y line=right,ytick={\minW,1,...,\maxW},yticklabel pos=right,
                   xlabel={},
                   ylabel={}]
      % curva de saturación:           
      \addplot[blue,samples=201,name path global=lineaSaturacion]
              {1000 / ((\Pt/1000)/(0.62198*1*\Pvs) -1.60777)};
      %
      \lineasVolumen{0.75}{0.95}{0.05} 
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: A full MWE would help here, otherwise we are just guessing.  Sometime you can get a macro to expand by putting it inside braces.  Sometimes you need to use something like domain/.expanded=...

Comment: I've just included a picture with a minimal example. I hope it is useful for you. Thank you very for your answer!

Comment: A MWE can be copied and executed as is.  Copy your source to a new file, then remove everything not related to the problem, then compile the edited file to make sure it reproduces the problem. Try not to use other data files, or at least provide copies as well.

Comment: I have post the overall code. I am apologise for my mistake.

Comment: If I understand what you want to do: clipping is probably an easier solution. Draw the purple lines, and then clip so that only the portion above the blue line shows. For details you will probably need someone more proficient in pgf and TikZ to help.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that option, but I would like to solve the original problem if possible.

Comment: It's a timing problem.  \addplot is expanded before \xx is computed.  It has to do with how pgfplots works.  Nothing is actually plotted until \end{axis}, but the options are all expanded immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution used `\pgfplotsextra`, `\path` and `\draw` instead of `\addplot`.

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[a4paper,landscape,
                left=1.5cm,right=1cm,
                top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,
        headsep=0cm,footskip=0cm]
               {geometry}

    \usepackage{pxfonts} % palatino con símbolos matemáticos (incompatible amsmath)           

    \usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
    \renewcommand\shorthandsspanish{} % evita conflictos con tikz (ver spanish.pdf y
                              % notas.txt)
    \spanishdecimal{,} %\decimalpoint

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    %\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \usepackage{fp}
    \usepackage{xifthen}

    \newcounter{id}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand\transformxdimension[1]{
        \pgfmathparse{((#1/\pgfplots@x@veclength)+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x}
    }
    \newcommand\transformydimension[1]{
        \pgfmathparse{((#1/\pgfplots@y@veclength)+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@y)/10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y}
    }
    \makeatother

    % PARÁMETROS DEL DIAGRAMA ******************************************************

    \newcommand{\ancho}{192mm}
    \newcommand{\alto}{122mm}

    \newcommand{\Pt}{101325} % en pascales (101325 a nivel del mar)

    \newcommand{\minTs}{-10} \newcommand{\maxTs}{55}
    \newcommand{\pasoTsPral}{5} \newcommand{\pasoTsSec}{1}  % para rejilla de Ts

    \newcommand{\minW}{0} \newcommand{\maxW}{33}

    \newcommand{\Pvs}{exp((16.461*x-114.86)/(x+231.67))}

    \newcommand{\lineasVolumen}[3]{%
      % #1,2 Volumen inicial, volumen final, #3 paso.
      % Líneas de volumen constante:
      \FPeval{\segundo}{(#1) + (#3)}

      \foreach \volumen in {#1,\segundo,...,#2}{%
        \path[samples=201,domain=\minTs:\maxTs,name path global=lineaVolumen]
          plot (axis cs: \x, {621.98*(((\Pt)*(\volumen))/(287 *(\x+273.159)) - 1)});
        \path [name intersections={of=lineaSaturacion and lineaVolumen,by=E}];
        % Para dibujar las coordenadas x,y de la intersección:
        \node[anchor=south, fill=white, fill opacity=0.75,text opacity=1] at (E) {
          \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
          \transformxdimension{\macrox}
          \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},%
          \transformydimension{\macroy}%
          \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult} 
        };
        \node at (E) { % sólo aquí funciona, pero \x sólo vale en otro entrecorchete
          \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
          \transformxdimension{\macrox}
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{\pgfmathresult}
          \global\edef\coordX{\xx}
        };
        \node at (E) {\coordX};
        \draw[red,samples=201,domain=\coordX:\maxTs,name path global=lineaVolumen]
          plot (axis cs: \x, {621.98*(((\Pt)*(\volumen))/(287 *(\x+273.159)) - 1)});
      };
    }

    % ******************************************************************************

    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}

    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[width=1.3*\ancho,height=1.3*\alto,
                   domain=\minTs:\maxTs,domain y=\minW:\maxW,
                   xmin=\minTs,xmax=\maxTs,ymin=\minW,ymax=\maxW,
                   title={},
                   axis x line=bottom,xtick={\minTs,-\pasoTsPral,...,\maxTs},
                   axis y line=right,ytick={\minW,1,...,\maxW},yticklabel pos=right,
                   xlabel={},
                   ylabel={}]
      % curva de saturación:           
      \addplot[blue,samples=201,name path global=lineaSaturacion]
              {1000 / ((\Pt/1000)/(0.62198*1*\Pvs) -1.60777)};
      %
      \pgfplotsextra{\lineasVolumen{0.75}{0.95}{0.05}}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Now the code works fine. I am very grateful for your help!